# как связать базу данных на сервере openscape с i18next

Tags: sql, reactjs, i18n

Делаю многоязычную страницу с i 18next react на трёх языках .
Локальные данные все отлично работает. Не могу найти решение для вывода данных по языкам из базы данных сервера. У меня только одна таблица с id, lang, name etc.

подскажите варианты или где искать, пожалуйста.

i18n
.use(Backend)
.use(LanguageDetector)
.use(initReactI18next)
.init({
fallbackLng: 'de',
debug: true,
detection: {
order: ['queryString', 'cookie'],
cach: ['cookie']
},
interpolation: {
escapaValue: false
},

});

export default i18n